# jqmobi with a canvas in mainframe

Tags: jqmobi, appframework

I'm trying to make a canvas in the main frame from jqmobi.

The user can drag and drop in the canvas. It works well whitout jqmobi... Now when i put it in the content frame, i am not able to touch or drag and drop. I removed the scroll option (overflow: hidden).

What can I do more to disable the touch listeners from jqmobi??

```
 <div id="jQUi">
 . . .
        <div id="content">
            <div title='canvas' id="main" class="panel" data-tab="navbar_home" style="overflow: hidden" selected="true">
                 <canvas id="can" width="500" height="500"> </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
 . . .
</div>
```